# How to select an argument + argument choice and use both options together in a statement

Tags: python, argparse

Working with this argument:

```
def get_args(arglist):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
        description=textwrap.dedent('''
           text '''))
    parser.add_argument('--add',
                    default='',
                    nargs='?',
                    choices=['user', 'database'],
                    help='Add user or database (default: %(default)s)')

    args = parser.parse_args(arglist) # Passing argument list into parse
    args_dict = vars(args)  # Dictionary for args
    return args, args_dict  # Return the parsed arguments
```

I need to perform logic that will read which `choice` was made and go down a path of if statements based on that choice.

Here is basically what I'm trying to do:

```
if args.add+args.user:
    print(f"do something to add user {args.add}")
if args.add+args.database:
    print(f"do something to add database {args.add}")
```

I want this CLI script to know what the user is trying to add (for now, a `user` or a `database`).

The end goal is that the user will enter `./myscript.py --add user USERNAME` to add a user.

Comment: Have you tried to use `if args.add == 'user':` and `if args.add == 'database':` ? If I understood the question, this should be enough...

Comment: not until you suggested it, thank you, it worked!

Comment: Glad to hear that! I will add this as the answer, could kindly accept it? :)

Comment: But I have one more issue now it seems... my output is `do something to add database database` but i need it to be `do something to add database MYDB`

Comment: of course I will :)

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more? Where MYDB came from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just compare the value stored in your argument to check what had the user entered:

```
if args.add == 'user':
    print(f"do something to add user {args.add}")
if args.add == 'database':
    print(f"do something to add database {args.add}")
```

**For the `USERNAME` or `MYDB` part**

A solution that came right now in my mind is to add one more argument. It could be a positional or optional too.

Positional:

```
parser.add_argument('name',
                    default='',
                    help='USERNAME or DATABASE name to be added (default: %(default)s)')
```

Script call: `./myscript.py USERNAME --add user` or `./myscript.py MYDB --add database`

Optional:

```
parser.add_argument('--name',
                    default='',
                    help='USERNAME or DATABASE name to be added (default: %(default)s)')
```

Script call: `./myscript.py --add user --name USERNAME` or `./myscript.py --add database --name MYDB`

Comment: This did answer the question, but now I'm seeing `do something to add database database` but i need it to be `do something to add database MYDB`

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more? Where MYDB came from?

Comment: Yes, `MYDB` would be for example: input = `./myscript --add database MYDB` .. basically it would be the name of the database that i want to add, whereas the `database` keyword would be just telling the script that what i want to add is a database.

Comment: I added a possible solution to this in the answer.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! my input is `./myscript.py --add database mydb`, output is `do something to add database mydb`

Comment: But how do I control placement of the `name` positional argument within the CLI command?

Comment: All the positional arguments will follow the established order created when you add the arguments to the parser. On the other hand, the optional arguments can be placed anywhere in the command since they will be identified by the '--arggument' or '-arg'. You can find more information in this [link](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/argparse.html).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Hemerson's answer you could also create a [subparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_subparsers) with a [mutually exclusive group](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_mutually_exclusive_group) containing the arguments `--database` and `--user`.

Here is an example:

```
import argparse


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='command')
    add_command = subparsers.add_parser('add', help='Add database or user.')
    add_group = add_command.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
    add_group.add_argument('--database')
    add_group.add_argument('--user')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.command == 'add':
        if args.user:
            print('Adding user:', args.user)
        if args.database:
            print('Adding database:', args.database)
```

Now you can call:

- `./myscript.py add --database MYDB`
- `./myscript.py add --user MYUSER`

But not:

- `./myscript.py add`
- `./myscript.py add --database MYDB --user MYUSER`